# How do I loop over a vector of strings and another vector of numbers at the same time in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I want to loop over an index of strings which correspond to columns of a dataframe (d) to put these columns into a new dataframe (h). But instead of copying the content of the columns, adding a distinct number to each column. The numbers are specified in the vector numvec. Here is my sample code:

```
   d<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:9,300,rep=TRUE)))
   d$rn<-replicate(1,"mystring")
   h<-as.data.frame(d[,6])
   colnames(d)<-c("first","second","third","fourth","fifth")
   trtvec<-colnames(d)
   numvec<-c(2,8,7,6,5)

   #loop for each trait
   for(i in seq_along(trtvec))
   {
       h$trtvec[i]<-d$trtvec[i]+numvec[i]

   }
```

Basically, already the first part

```
h$trtvec[i]<-d$trtvec[i]
```

doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `replicate(1,"mystring")` is at least strange, you replicate *one* time? Also, there are no such things as `h$trtvec` and `d$trtvec`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, just for having a column I can copy. In my real dataframe, they would be different, but I didn't know how to have different strings in this column.

Comment: `trtvec` is a character vector, you cannot add numbers and characters. Do you want to `paste(trtvec, numvec)`?

Comment: With trtvec, I want to iterate over the columns and copy the content of the columns to h, adding to each value of the content the respective number of the numvec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following does what you want.
It uses a `apply` loop to add `numvec` to each 5 elements of the rows of data frame `d`.

```
h <- d[6]
numvec <- c(2, 8, 7, 6, 5)

h1 <- cbind(h, t(apply(d[1:5], 1, '+', numvec)))
head(h1)
#        rn first second third fourth fifth
#1 mystring     3     11     9     12    11
#2 mystring     8     17     8     10     8
#3 mystring     8     13     8     15    12
#4 mystring     8     12    12     10     7
#5 mystring    10     17    11     15     5
#6 mystring     8     12    10      6    14
```

If you want column `rn` as the last column, use `cbind.data.frame` and change the order of the arguments.

```
h2 <- cbind.data.frame(t(apply(d[1:5], 1, '+', numvec)), h)
head(h2)
#  first second third fourth fifth       rn
#1     3     11     9     12    11 mystring
#2     8     17     8     10     8 mystring
#3     8     13     8     15    12 mystring
#4     8     12    12     10     7 mystring
#5    10     17    11     15     5 mystring
#6     8     12    10      6    14 mystring
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sapply on the selected column names like this

```
data <- data.frame(a = rep(0, 100) b = rep(1, 100), c = rep(2, 100))

# using a named vector to simplify indexing
num.vec <- c(a = 2, b = 3)

# add the corresponding number to selected columns
new.data <- sapply(names(num.vec), FUN = function(x) data[,x] + num.vec[x])

head(new.data, 1)

     a  b
[1,] 2  4
```